# What's the difference between the "Mime Mail" and "Mail MIME" modules?

Tags: emails

There appear to be two ways of sending HTML e-mail using Drupal:

- [Mail MIME](http://drupal.org/project/mailmime) with [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail)
- [Mime Mail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail)

Mime Mail has significantly more installs, but it depends on [Mailsystem](http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem), which is maintained by the maintainer of Mail MIME.

What is the difference between these modules?  Is one a fork of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many more than 2 ways to send mail with Drupal. But, the modules you are showing are not for *sending* mail at all, they are there only to encode / decode mime content.

The problem you are facing is common in Drupal land: Developers re-inventing the wheel. You will often bump into modules that do similar tasks.

Mime mail has more support, is much more active, and has more features, (it can decode incoming html mail if I understood correctly).   I would go for this over Mail Mime with HTML Mail Pear class.

As for *sending* the emails, I can **strongly** recommend [SMTP Authentication module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) if you don't want to use Drupal's built-in mechanism.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the modules don't actually send e-mail.  That's a very important point I overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

Mail MIME just provides integration with the PEAR Mail_MIME class to encode and decode Mime Mails. Other modules can then integrate with it, for example HTML Mail to use it to send Mails.

Mime Mail on the other hand, is the same as those two modules combined, it contains both the functions to deal with mime encoded mails and exposes itself to Drupal so that mails from other modules are sent with it.

Neither of these modules actually allow you, as a user, to send mails, they deal with mails sent by other modules. There is a small exception there, namely that Mime Mail comes with Rules integration that allows to send HTML formatted mails.

Answer (score 0):

First, I overlooked this when I originally asked my question, but there is a [post on Drupal.org by the Mail MIME maintainer](http://drupal.org/node/1126118#comment-4343178) describing the differences between the two modules.

I spent the last few hours evaluating both the modules and here are my thoughts:

- Mail MIME is much more modular than Mime Mail.  The maintainer has created a large number of modules that one can pick and choose from to get the features required.  Personally, I prefer this approach.
- However, in my case there was no easy way to install the Pear classes on my server, so I ended up going with Mime Mail.